# CSS3 Transitions/Animations not working

Tags: animation, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to wrap my head around CSS3 when it comes to transitions and animations. I have some boxes and I'd like the title and description to animate when hovering over the box.

In order to get this to work, I thought I had to define the animations when the :hover event for the wrapper element is fired. I suppose I'm just not executing this correctly in my CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/qXdNc/

```
.feature-box, .feature-box-title, .feature-box-image, .feature-box-desc {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -moz-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -o-transition: all 300ms linear;
    -ms-transition: all 300ms linear;
    transition: all 300ms linear;
}
.feature-box:hover .feature-box-title {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromRight 300ms ease;
}
.feature-box:hover .feature-box-desc {
    -webkit-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -moz-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
    -ms-animation: moveFromBottom 500ms ease;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing transitions with animations, you shouldn't do that.

The animations keyframes `moveFromBottom`, `moveFromRight`, etc are not defined in your CSS.

Transitions define how the DOM should be animated when a property changes, but they don't define which property changes. I like to think in transitions as a shortcut to animations.

Animations are much more complex, but much more powerful. But I don't think you need animations to achieve what you want.

I changed your jsFiddle a little bit, I removed the animations and added a rotation using the transitions. Here is the link:

http://jsfiddle.net/canassa/qXdNc/1/